# Mongodb get Effective Lock

Tags: mongodb

I´m trying to calculate the Effective Lock %, like MMS does. I think I could get it via MMS API, but most of our mongo instances currently are not monitored in MMS (and probably never will).

All I have is a very rudimentary globalLock calculation using the GlobalLock totalTime and lockTime, but these kind of metrics does not exist for the individual locks and Im not really sure how to interpret a calculation like that with the timeLockedMicros and timeAquiringMicros. Could you guys point me towards the light?

Answer (score 1):

I dont realy try it or sure that is true but i read same info on webs

```
user_load+system_load+table as %    (how mush use) 
,CPU                        as %    (how mush use)
,network_processor_load     as %    (how mush use)
memory                      as %    (how mush use)
combine will give you the % that you wont...
```

at lest im hope so XD...

sorry... if it not ture ^o.0^ but still my brain was work hard for this...

sooo easy on me...

**and dont - star pliz**